# How can I make a bootstrap navbar mobile friendly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**I don't have a specific code example, just looking for a general answer.**

I know my navbar doesn't resize well in mobile, so is there a good/correct way to fix this? Someone mentioned using CSS `@media` queries, but I don't know anything about them.

If I do need media queries, what's a good resource to learn about them? Everything else looks fine when I use `col-md-()`, just not the navbar.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
  font-size: 175%;
}

li {
  float: right;
  text-align: left
}

link {
  link
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #000000;
}

.main-section {
  background-image: url(../img/back.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 1000px;
  color: white;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.main {
  padding: 400px 0px 360px 0px;
  text-shadow: 1px black;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}

.headers-bfg {
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 35px;
}

.fa-circle {
  color: gray;
  font-size: .4em;
  padding-top: 23px
}

.info-panel {
  padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}

.balloon-sect {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.flower-sect {
  background-color: #f4f6f9;
}

.gift-sect {
  background-color: #ce6640;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Balloons Flowers and Gifts</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bfg.css">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Spent two hours trying to figure out why my customized CSS wouldn't load in, then realized that I put it in front of bootstrap... -->

  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7a267289ed.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bfg.css">

  <link rel="icon" href="img/icon.png">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid main-section">
    <nav class=" navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="headers-bfg">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BFG</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand col-xs-2" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul class=" nav navbar-nav ">
          <li><a href="#">Balloons</a></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-small fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
          <li><a href="#">Flowers</a></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gifts</a></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hours</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-center main">
          <h1>Balloons Flowers and Gifts</h1>
          <h3>The perfect way to brighten someone's day, and make them smile!</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-center info-panel balloon-sect">
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Balloons</h2>
        </a>
        <p> Our hand crafted balloon creations are a hit at every! We have a wide variety of colored and themed balloons ranging from Pokemon GO to a life sized stormtrooper! We also do balloon things for events!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-center info-panel flower-sect">
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Flowers</h2>
        </a>
        <p>Our Flowers are perfect for any occasion! We have a wide variety all year round, just be sure to call for availability! We can do prom flowers, funeral arrangements, and everything in between!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-center info-panel gift-sect">
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Gifts</h2>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Hours</h2>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  html css twitter-bootstrap
```

Comment: if you are using bootstrap navbar then it should resize correctly, It will be great if you can share the code

Comment: @shubhamkhandelwal I added code

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more about CSS `@media` queries here:

[templatemonster.com/blog/css-media-queries...](https://www.templatemonster.com/blog/css-media-queries-for-all-devices-and-browsers-including-ie7-and-ie8/)

It explains about media queries and how to make it work on other devices, and it includes an IE 7 and IE 8 fallback mechanism.

IF you want to learn Bootstrap, you can use bootstrap GUI designing tool:

[codepley.com/go/bp/new](https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/new)

Answer (score 0):

I do two things. (When the first one not working properly, I'll go to the second method.)

1. First Method.

   I search for common mobile device sizes and used them to adjust the navbar according to it. Common sizes are 320px, 375px, 480px, 640px, 768px, 1024px.

   @media (max-width: 600px) {
   Your code here
   }
2. Second Method

   If my common sizes are not correctly working I tried to reduce the sizes one by one and try to get the absolutely correct matches that may not destroy the website.